# Is it possible to use React Material UI, redux and react-form-hook together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am exploring several online tutorials to learn how these technologies can be used together to build React TypeScript app.

I have two specific questions:

1. Is it possible to use these three technologies together? I came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evDxlqnsxXc) video which explains react-hook-form with redux but not Material-UI. `index.js` [wraps](https://github.com/satansdeer/rhf-wizard-form/blob/95666280873ccdcca890274a2ac9d14bb373c674/src/index.js#L11) everything (that is, `App` component which contains router routes to `Step1.js`, `Step2.js` etc.) with react-redux `Provider`. So, to introduce material-UI, all I have to do is to wrap Material UI components inside react-hook-form [`Controller`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) in files say [`Step1.js`](https://github.com/satansdeer/rhf-wizard-form/blob/95666280873ccdcca890274a2ac9d14bb373c674/src/Step1.js)?
2. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCRaGQmUiQE&list=PLzYM-WGWIJDQaDnYnaaQHgStfoL200xF2&index=2) video says that react-hook-form `FormProvider` requires [`useFormContext`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext/) which is based on react context API. Does this mean that we cannot use redux with `FormProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Material UI is simply for the view layer of your components. Redux is a global state management tool, and react-form-hook is for forms. I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use them together.

Even though the FormProvider uses Context API, you can still have your project's global state in a Redux store. If you do want to use Context API, it's practically the same as Redux, so it's up to you.

Comment: Need more clarity. **Q3.** Do you mean Yes to Q1 by first paragraph? ***Q4.** What do you mean by last two sentences in last paragraph? You said "you can still have your project's global state in a Redux store. " But, how can I make `FormProvider` refer redux and not `ContextAPI` (as `FormProvider` is implemented to use `ContextAPI`)?